# Change characterstic value type from hex to dec

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a project where i have to send ble custom Characterstic to an Android app. I'm developing the Project using the stm32wb55 nucleo board. I'm trying to use the example BLE_Template for Testing. I achieved to send a value with the function Custom_STM_App_Update_Char(characteristicName, uint8_t *Value); but the issue is that i receive hexadecimal value of the value which i declared as decimal. How can I make the value appear decimal in the android app?

I declared the value as decimal but received the value in the Android app as hexadecimal

Comment: BLE does not send values as decimal or hex, they will always be send as bytes. So this is simply a problem of displaying the received number in your android app. Please [edit] your question to add the part of your app where you receive the value and want to display it as decimal.

Comment: It is not my App. I used the BLE Scanner APP.

Comment: Which app are you using? Maybe it offers an option to change the display mode to decimal?